# AngularJS - updating DOM with result of service method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got this markup:

```
<div ng-controller="AutoDeployController as autoDeploy">
   <input type="text" ng-model="autoDeploy.message">
   <p>Message: {{ autoDeploy.message }}</p>
</div>

<button ng-click="autoDeploy.change()">change</button>
```

This method in my controller:

```
model = this;

model.change = function(){
    model.message = AutoDeployService.returnOne();
};
```

This method in my service module:

```
function returnOne(){
    return "one";
}
```

When I debug it using chrome I can see that `model.message` gets changed to `"one"` and if I type in the text box it changes `model.message`, and any other fields with `model.message` change on the fly... so why isn't the DOM updating when I click the button?

I feel like it may involve `$compile` or another system variable based on my experience with using buttons to create and add DOM objects, but I'm not sure when/why the system variables are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your button is outside your autoDeploy controller. Move that button inside the div with the controller, and it will call the change method.

```
<div ng-controller="AutoDeployController as autoDeploy">
   <input type="text" ng-model="autoDeploy.message">
   <p>Message: {{ autoDeploy.message }}</p>
   <button ng-click="autoDeploy.change()">change</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Weird... I already tried that as I mentioned above in my first comment on @jrDeveloper's; it works now though. It must've been something else causing the issue.

Comment: If it can be answered without seeing the rest of my code: Why is it that my other buttons that inject directive templates work outside of the div with the controller, but this one does not? Maybe because the functionality for this one is in the service rather than already in the controller?

Comment: The key is you're trying to access the controller known as "autoDeploy", so you have to be within the div where it's set. If your other buttons don't try to call a method on the autoDeploy controller, they would not need to be within that controller div.